# Increment by one in for loop

Tags: f#

I've got a simple for loop like this

```
let mutable index = 0
let mutable indx = 0
for c in list do 
    //some code
    index <- indx
    indx <- indx + 1
```

Basically what I want to do is iterate over a list of objects and search for a specific object in the list, then set index variable to the index of the object I'm looking for.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the last line, where I think I'm incrementing indx by one, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why wouldn't you do the functional approach with no mutation?

```
let my_predicate item = // some condition on item

let index = list |> Seq.findIndex my_predicate

// index will be bound to the first item in list for which my_predicate returns true
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're only trying to find the index of some item in a sequence, plinth has the idiomatic solution. But I thought I would explain why your approach won't work. In F#, there is no way to exit loops early (i.e., no `break`/`continue`). Typically, you would use recursion to accomplish this:

```
let tryFindIndex f list =
  let rec loop i = function
    | [] -> None
    | head::tail when f head -> Some i
    | _::tail -> loop (i + 1) tail
  loop 0 list

//Usage
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5] |> tryFindIndex (fun x -> x = 3)
> val it : int option = Some 2
```